# Stored Procedure Text history

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am not that much well versed in SQL Server. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I wanted to know if we can get the **history** of the text of the stored procedures?

I had modified a procedure on the server and now I want to get the previous text of that stored procedure? I know we can get the last modified date or history of the procedure when it was modified. Is there anyway to get the previous text of the procedure?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can restore the text entered when you have closed that particular query window. When in the current window Ctrl+Z or Ctrl+Y will help as known by all

Comment: @Aishvarya Karthik: Thanks for the reply. I have no copy of the proc nor do I had use sp_helptext to get the prior version. I know we can use Ctrl+z or Ctrl+Y but for that I need to have that old text with me which I dont.

Comment: I don't think the text restoration will be possible

Comment: Your SQL code for your stored procedures should be kept in a **source control system** like any other source code, too - and there, yes, you can easily retrieve older versions of that stored procedure's code - but not in SQL Server directly, it doesn't store a history of copies of your stored procedure code - that's **up to YOU!**

Comment: Yup thats correct @marc_c and Prince Jea and we do store the proc in the version and even I maintain the hard copies of the proc. But its unfortunate that ONLY that proc got missed to be added in version and so the things got fussy :(.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cant recover it once you update your stored procedure. One thing to avoid this in the future is save your query before modifying it. SQL SERVER doesnt have a History Feature like JAVA.There are also third party tools which you can use if you want to connect your database to a source control.

[Click Here](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/)